# User-defined Functions

Tags: c

I was trying to calculate the area of both a triangle and a circle using 3 separate user defined functions within main. After compiling, the GetInt function worked properly but the other two functions' calculations are not printing on the screen accurately for my c program on Microsoft Visual Studio 2013. What am i doing wrong?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define PI 3.14159
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int GetInt(void);
double CalcTriangleArea(int base, int height);
double CalcCircleArea(int radius);

int main(void)
{
   printf("%d", GetInt());
   printf("%f", CalcTriangleArea);
   printf("%f", CalcCircleArea);

   return(0);
}

int GetInt(void)
{
   int radius, base, height;

   printf("What is the radius of the circle? \n\n");
   scanf("%d", &radius);

   printf("What is the base of the triangle? \n\n");
   scanf("%d", &base);

   printf("\nthe height of the triangle? \n\n");
   scanf("%d", &height);

   return (radius, base, height);
}

double CalcTriangleArea(int base, int height)
{
   double triangleArea;
   printf("Triangle area is %.2f \n\n", triangleArea = .5*base*height);

   return(0);
}

double CalcCircleArea(int radius)

{
   double circleArea;
   printf("Circle area is %.4f \n\n", circleArea = PI * pow(radius, 2));

   return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`CalcTriangleArea` Is not calling the function, it's using the functions address. Try `CalcTriangleArea()`

edit: Just noticed `CalcTriangleArea` takes parameters - you'll need to pass those in too.

edit: And how do you think you can return 3 values?

Answer (score 0):

For `CalcTriangleArea` and `CalcCircleArea` there is no need to have the printf's in main if you're printing the results in your functions.  You could simply call them in main like so:

```
GetInt();
CalcTriangleArea(base, height);
```

Also, if this is the approach you are taking (printing results in the function and returning 0), your functions could be declared like so:

```
void myFunction(int arg1, int arg2)
```

Since your are not returning anything that you are using, using a void type allows you to have a function without an explicit return.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, when I call the functions in main, I have to initialize the variables, which would be fine except it prints three times on the screen instead of just once: